# What is the "Fee payment" as described in the Legal section at the end?

Tags: application, legal, fees

In reference to the patent: [US5222141](https://www.google.com/patents/US5222141)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintaining a patent costs money. Those fees have to be paid regularly or the patent "dies".

Comment: So this is what is occurring? Sep 11, 1996 FPAY Fee payment 
Year of fee payment: 4 

Sep 29, 2000 FPAY Fee payment 
Year of fee payment: 8 

Sep 29, 2004 FPAY Fee payment 
Year of fee payment: 12

Comment: Yes, that means that the fees were paid.